# Login issue through Selenium webdriver for Myntra.com

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the Registration and Login process of Myntra.com using selenium.

I already registered once using selenium. But the problem is when i am trying to register once more using the same userId and password, a popup is generating saying "**email-id already exist**". I want to handle this popup .That if this particular text is present then i'll go to login page. But i'm unable to handle that popup.

[image: Attached the screenshot of the popup]

**Using the following code :**

```
   public class Myntra {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://Selenium/Selenium Setup/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver Driver= new ChromeDriver();

        Driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("myntra");
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        List<WebElement> findElements = Driver.findElements(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a"));
        for (WebElement webElement : findElements)
        {
             if(webElement.getAttribute("href").equalsIgnoreCase("https://www.myntra.com/")) {
                Driver.navigate().to(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
                System.out.println("Navigation Success");
                break;
             }
        }
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id=\"desktop-header-cnt\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]")).click();
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id=\"desktop-header-cnt\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]")).click();

        //Register page

        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.name("email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.name("password")).sendKeys("123");
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.name("mobile")).sendKeys("1234567892");
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.id("male")).click();
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id=\"mountRoot\"]/div/div/div/form/fieldset[2]/button")).click();
        Alert alert =  Driver.switchTo().alert();  
        String str= alert.getText();
        System.out.println(str);

    }

   }
```

Comment: Is it a native alert or HTML that displays a pop-up? If later, can you add the HTML source of the pop-up?

Comment: It is very difficult to get the html source of the popup...because the popup is getting vanished after 2 secs. :(

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on Register insert the following code:

**Note:** After clicking on register button, Don't give any sleep time.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p[class = 'notify-icon-text']").getText().equals("The email you entered already exists")){
doLogin(); //call login method with userName and password
}
```